# Connecting to WCF service in Windows Phone 8 (C#) by using domain credentials

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 project (in C#) with a service reference. Is it possible to set http client credential type to NTLM? I need to provide domain name, user and password.

I'm using BasicHttpBinding with TransportCredentialOnly option. This is done in
*.ClientConfig file:

```
<configuration>
 <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="WSSoap" maxBufferSize="XXX" maxReceivedMessageSize="XXX">
       <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" />
      </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
        <endpoint address="http://<address>" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSSoap" contract="WorkListService.WSSoap"
            name="WSSoap" />
      </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

But I also need to set ClientCredentialType to NTLM and provide ServiceCredentials: Domain, UserName and Password.

This can be easily done in Windows Store apps by implementing partial ConfigureEndpoint method of the generated service class. But I don't know how to do it in Windows Phone 8.

I've noticed that only UserName and Password is available (basic auth):

```
*.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName
*.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any phone development experience.  Where is what I do at a C# Service Level.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://whatever.com");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

NetworkCredential networkCredentials = new NetworkCredential();
networkCredentials.Domain = "Domain";
networkCredentials.UserName = "User";
networkCredentials.Password = "Pass";

CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(uri, "Basic", networkCredentials); //NTLM can be used here, but Basic usually works.

request.Credentials = cc;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    ...
}
```